# Heroku automatically changing state from up to down

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have default node-js starting script and Twitch bot on my Dyno.
But every hour I'm getting in my logs:

```
2016-04-25T20:28:10.328746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-04-25T20:28:10.327874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-04-25T20:28:13.451043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-04-25T20:28:15.026707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Why is this happening? How do I prevent Heroku from changing the state?

Comment: If an app has a web dyno, and that web dyno receives no traffic in a 30 minute period, the web dyno will sleep. In addition to the web dyno sleeping, the worker dyno (if present) will also sleep. That's why I Think.

Comment: Thanks! Any advice on how to keep it active, or wake it if it's gone dormant?